# Unexpected token, expected ; body {

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4

I want to load my css files.

inside my component:

```
import '../assets/home/css/style.css'
```

I'm using 'style-loader', 'css-loader' but I got this error message:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/sm_emamian/Desktop/react js/shadyab/app/assets/home/css/style.css: Unexpected token, expected ; (1:5)
[0] > 1 | body {
[0]     |      ^
[0]   2 |   text-transform: capitalize;
[0]   3 |   font-family: FontAwesome,iransans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
[0]   4 |   background-color: #F2F2F2;
[0]     at Parser.pp$5.raise (/Users/sm_emamian/Desktop/react js/shadyab/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
```

my webpack.config.js:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
```

my style.css:

```
body {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: FontAwesome,iransans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: #505050; }
```

...

**updated**:

my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin')

var DEBUG = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')

if (DEBUG) {
  require('dotenv').config()
}

var config = {
  devtool: DEBUG ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : false,
  entry: {
    app: ['./app/app'],
    vendor: [
      'react',
      'react-router',
      'redux',
      'react-dom',
      'lodash',
      'bluebird',
      'humps',
      'history'
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [ path.join(__dirname, 'app'), 'node_modules' ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV', 'API_BASE_URL']),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


if (DEBUG) {
  config.entry.app.push('webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr')

  config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      filname: 'vendor.js'
    })
  ])
  config.output.publicPath = '/'
  config.module.rules.unshift({
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'react-hot-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    include: __dirname
  })
} else {
  config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      filname: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
  ])
}

module.exports = config
```

Comment: And this isn't an error in your css file?

Comment: no, because it's a template and I want to convert to reactjs. is it possible this error occure for my gulpfile.js?

Comment: @Herr Derb added my style.css codes.

Comment: Seems that styles loaders are fine. Can you setup a github project to check your problem? Also, you can review this [webpack-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) - despite is using webpack 4, the styles config is similar.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Did you find a fix ??

Answer (score 0):

Please try this config

```
 {
   test: /\.css$/,
   use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Are you able to show your whole webpack file? One more question, do you have declared `presets` for babel-loader in `.babelrc` file ? I think it is looking like more jsx parsing issue than css.

Comment: my .babelrc: `{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [ "babel-plugin-rewire" ]
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: Your config is looking good to me, would you take a look at [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#usage) ?